# Retrieving lync presence indication and showcase on linux OS apps

Tags: linux

I want to showcase Lync presence indication(Online, offline, away etc) in my Linux based oracle application for all my application users. The problem i'm facing is i 'm not able to fetch real time presence information of the lync users so as i can replicate the same in my application.

Google helped me get few Lync clients like SIPE and Pidgin.
http://unifiedme.blogspot.in/2013/01/lync-on-linux.html

I need additional info 
-- How can i read the presence status data from lync database so that I can add the presence status to my Linux based application.

-- How can i use Lync in Linux OS

Comment: Why the *heck* is this migrated to here?

Answer (score 0):

SIPE is a Pidgin protocol plug-in designed to give Pidgin and related applications interoperability with Lync.

Probably the simplest way to enable SIPE in your own application is to integrate the Pidgin backend, called libpurple.